# change in cell content of salary or bonus or deduction in table cells automatically affect in total

Tags: jquery

Hi i have table have 5 column

```
Name   Salary Bonus Deduction Total
Ahmed  500     500    100      900
```

calculation of total is
`Total=Salary+Bonus-Deduction`
and total in red color according to my code
what i need actually if i changed in Salary cell or Bonus cell or Deduction cell  affect in total cell
suppose i added row above then edit salary 
from 500 to 2000 meaning in this time row will be as bellow
Ahmed  2000   500  100    2400
total will be 2400 with green color 
 how to do by changing cell in table affect in total

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#btn").click(function () {
                    var x = $("#txt1").val();
                    var y = $("#txt2").val();
                    var z = $("#txt3").val();
                    var M = $("#txt4").val();
                    var L = parseInt(y) + parseInt(z) - parseInt(M);

                    $("#tb").append("<tr> <td>" + x + "</td> <td>" + y + "</td> <td>" + z + "<td>" + M + "</td><td>" + L + "</td></tr>");
                    $("#tb tr").each(function () {
                        var total = $(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").html();

                        if(parseInt(total)>1000)
                        {
                            $(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").css("background-color", "green");
                        }
                        if (parseInt(total) < 1000) {
                            $(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").css("background-color", "red");
                        }
                        if (parseInt(total) == 1000) {
                            $(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").css("background-color", "yellow");
                        }

                    });


                });


                $("#tb").on("click", "tr", function () {

                    $(this).find("td").slice(0, 4).prop("contenteditable", true);

                });



            });
        </script>
        <style>
             .red{
        color:#ff0000;
        font-weight:bold;
        }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Name<input type="text" id="txt1" /><br />
            Salary<input type="text" id="txt2" /><br />
            Bonus<input type="text" id="txt3" /><br />
            Deduction<input type="text" id="txt4" /><br />
            <input type="button" value="add" id="btn" />


            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                                Name


                        </td>
                        <td>

                                Salary


                        </td>
                        <td>

                                Bonus


                        </td>
                        <td>

                                Deduction


                        </td>
                        <td>
                            total
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tb" class="tb1"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you add the property contenteditable when you click on a table row to each table cells to keep updated the total field you need to use:

- focus event to save the current value of the cell
- keydown event in order to avoid return key and in future to accept only numbers
- blur event to test if the cell content changed and if so recalculate the total:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#btn").click(function () {
    var x = $("#txt1").val();
    var y = $("#txt2").val();
    var z = $("#txt3").val();
    var M = $("#txt4").val();
    var L = parseInt(y) + parseInt(z) - parseInt(M);

    // reset fields
    $('[id^="txt"]').val('');
    
    $("#tb").append("<tr> <td>" + x + "</td> <td>" + y + "</td> <td>" + z + "<td>" + M + "</td><td>" + L + "</td></tr>");
    $("#tb tr").each(function () {
      var total = $(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").html();
      if (parseInt(total) > 1000) {
        $(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").css("background-color", "green");
      }
      if (parseInt(total) < 1000) {
        $(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").css("background-color", "red");
      }
      if (parseInt(total) == 1000) {
        $(this).find("td:nth-child(5)").css("background-color", "yellow");
      }
    });
  });
  $("#tb").on("click", "tr", function (e) {
    $(this).find("td").slice(0, 4).prop("contenteditable", true);
  });

  $(document).on('focus', "#tb tr td", function (e) {
    if ($(this).index() > 0) {
      $(this).data('orig', this.textContent);
    }
  });

  $(document).on('keydown', "#tb tr td", function (e) {
    if ($(this).index() > 0) {
      if (e.keyCode === 10 || e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).on('blur', "#tb tr td", function (e) {
    if (($(this).index() > 0) && ($(this).data('orig') != this.textContent)) {
      var cells = $(this).parent().find('td');
      var Salary = +cells.eq('1').text();
      var Bonus = +cells.eq('2').text();
      var Deduction = +cells.eq('3').text();
      cells.eq('4').text(Salary + Bonus - Deduction).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div>
    Name<input type="text" id="txt1"/><br/>
    Salary<input type="text" id="txt2"/><br/>
    Bonus<input type="text" id="txt3"/><br/>
    Deduction<input type="text" id="txt4"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="add" id="btn"/>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Salary
            </td>
            <td>
                Bonus
            </td>
            <td>
                Deduction
            </td>
            <td>
                total
            </td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tb" class="tb1"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```